# Laravel custom package helper autoload

Tags: php, laravel

I'm developing a custom laravel package for my needs, and discovered strange issue. My package is supposed to use custom helper function called t().

```
function t($string, array $options = [])
{
    // Function code goes here
}
```

It is located in my package folder, right near the package service provider.
The service provider itself loads successfully, but helper file is not. I added following lines "autoload" section of the package's composer.json, just as I saw in other package:

```
"files": [
        "src/helpers.php"
    ]
```

then I dumped autoload. Everything works fine but this t() function. It's not found. What am I doing wrong?

P.S.: sure, I can include it in package service provider using require_once, but what is composer for either way?)

**UPDATE**
package composer.json:

```
{
  "name": "astatroth/laravel-i18n",
   "require": {
     "astatroth/laravel-config": "^1.0"
    },
  "license": "MIT",
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": ".......",
      "email": "........"
    },
    {
      "name": ".......",
      "email": "........"
    }
  ],
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Astatroth\\LaravelI18n\\": "src/"
    },
    "files": [
      "src/helpers.php"
    ]
  },
  "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

Package file structure:

```
laravel-i18n
  config
  src
    I18nServiceProvider.php
    helpers.php
  composer.json
```

Comment: Make absolutely sure your path is correct.

Comment: It is correct. As it is in laravelcollective/html package:
   ` "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Collective\\Html\\": "src/"
    },
    "files": [
      "src/helpers.php"
    ]
  }`

Comment: Could you post your full `composer.json` file and file structure?

Answer (score 1):

> My package

Packages or libraries by design does not support *Composer* configuration files, in other words `composer.json` file from your package folder is never read.

To workaround this problem, use `vcs` type instead of `package` when requiring the sources.

Related:

- [Why using PSR4 autoload doesn't add any classes into classmap/namespaces file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47497818/55075)
- [Using `autoload` in package doesn't generate classmap](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/6846#issuecomment-347161643) at *GitHub*

Answer (score 0):

Please run `composer update` if you use repositories symlink for adding your package to laravel project. I had a same issue, running `composer dump-autload` doesn't work, because your vendor folder not updated with your new file.
Hope this can solve your issue.

Comment: well that was not nice it installed like hundreds of laravel packages in a package...