# Why using PSR4 autoload doesn't add any classes into classmap/namespaces file?

Tags: psr-4, composer-php

I've got the following `composer.json` file:

```
{
  "require-dev": {
    "queueit/KnownUser.V3.PHP": "dev-master"
  },
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "package",
      "package": {
        "name": "queueit/KnownUser.V3.PHP",
        "version": "dev-master",
        "source": {
          "type": "git",
          "url": "https://github.com/kenorb-contrib/KnownUser.V3.PHP.git",
          "reference": "task/composer-autoloader"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

However upon running `composer install`, the namespaces or classes aren't added into `autoload_classmap.php` or `autoload_namespaces.php` in `vendor/composer`.

Before that I've added into project's `composer.json` these lines:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "QueueIT\\": ""
    }
}
```

in order to scan for the class/namespaces within the current folder and the file looks like:

```
$ cat vendor/queueit/KnownUser.V3.PHP/composer.json 
{
    "name": "queueit/knownuserv3",
    "description": "The Queue-it Security Framework is used to ensure that end users cannot bypass the queue by adding a server-side integration to your server.",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3"
    },
    "license":"LGPL-3.0",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "QueueIT\\": ""
        }
    }
}
```

Executing `dump-autoload` manually doesn't take any effect as well as follow:

```
$ composer dump-autoload -o
Generating optimized autoload files
$ grep -R QueueIT vendor/composer/
(no results)
```

To confirm that's the case, here is the shell command to test it:

```
$ php -r 'require __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php"; use QueueIT\KnownUserV3\SDK\KnownUser; new KnownUser;'
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'QueueIT\KnownUserV3\SDK\KnownUser' not found in Command line code:1
```

However the classmap is generated when executing `composer dump-autoload -o` directly in the project folder it-self (within `vendor/queueit/KnownUser.V3.PHP/` folder).

Why my autoload definition in project's `composer.json` doesn't take any effect when run from the top folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [@stof](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5350733/christophe-coevoet) [comment at GitHub](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/6846#issuecomment-347161643), *Composer* doesn't support loading of `composer.json` file from the repositories of the type `package`. The goal of a `package` type is to download projects which are *not* supporting *Composer*. Therefore `composer.json` file is *never* read.

Solution is to use `vcs` type instead. Here is the `composer.json` which should work:

```
{
  "require": {
    "queueit/knownuserv3": "dev-master"
  },
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "https://github.com/queueit/KnownUser.V3.PHP"
    }
  ]
}
```

Otherwise "you would have to copy the project metadata entirely in your package repository, and this is harder to maintain".